# Foursquare API Venue search, restrict by country and zip code

Tags: api, foursquare, http-get

I am able to restrict venue search to either a country or zip code, but not both.

I am aware the following example is not possible, but what I am trying to achieve is something like this:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=COUNTRYCODE&near=ZIPCODE

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass in "[Postal Code], [countrycode]" as a single string into the near parameter and that should work